# Pair programming. How?

Tags: pair-programming

I always want to try some pair programming especially with the one who is more experienced programmer than I am. But how can it be done? Are there any websites where people can collaborate and find partners or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually pair-programming is not done just for sharing technical expertise. It was mainly introduced for people working in projects for

- sharing project knowledge among the team members for a common understanding
- reviewing the code as part of development, thereby, decreasing the number of unwanted surprises in large projects.

There could be many other advantages, but these are the main advantages to do pair-programming.
Coming back to your question on whether its done in any site. Even for open-source development, its done as part of some code-jam kind of sessions. Try to find a dev next door that's a best choice to be made.

Happy Hacking!

Comment: Are there any *wanted* surprises in programming projects?

Comment: @Michael, pizza, anyone? ;-)

Comment: @Michael There's the "it worked the first time I tried it?!" surprise.

Comment: @JoshuaCarmody: that tends to make me suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

Pair programming is generally, performed with two partners in person.  One is actively generating the code while the other is observing checking the code as it is generated.  The two programmers switch positions every 20 minutes.

If you are attempting to improve your coding while working remotely.  You may want to find a programming mentor who would be willing to work with you via a system like GoToMeeting.  You can take turns sharing your screens and actively reviewing each others code.

If that isn't feasible another way to improve you coding is by submitting some of your work for review.